# Почему бы не запретить минусовать новичков и позволить комментировать их вопросы только стандартными комментариями

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, новички

Из списка, например: "Ваш вопрос нарушает такой то пункт правил (ссылка)".
 Часто новички не читают мануалов, неправильно понимают предназначение сайте, отсутствует интуитивное понимание "правильного" вопроса, в общем добросовестно заблуждаются без каких-либо злых намерений.
 "Старые" участники тоже без злых намерений начинают минусовать и иронизировать, мол, тут не фриланс, мол скоро начнут сложение двух числе просить запрограммировать (тоже, без всякой ненависти). Но бедный новичок воспринимает все это как травлю, а вовсе не как дружеское и доброжелательное (или равнодушное) подкалывание.
 Если не [оттолкнуть](https://habr.com/ru/post/311322/) такого участника, то он, скорее всего, исправится, и сообщество может приобрести нового полезного участника (а может и гения, просто протупившего в самом начале). Вот когда далее не исправится, то тогда ладно уж, валяйте...

Так как поведение и законное раздражение "дедов" так же объяснимо, простительно и неизбежно (что и говорить, сам не без греха), бессмысленно ограничиваться [призывами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043351/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8) **"@nickname  — новый участник. Будьте дружелюбны к нему и не забывайте про нормы поведения."**, поэтому предлагаю сделать такое ограничение на уровне движка форума

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что в данном случае является "стандартными комментариями"?

Comment: @RTK то есть не комментарий, написанный от руки, а предустоновленный набор сообщений, выбираемый, скажем, в комбобоксе с указанием типычных ошибок новичков

Comment: как в таком случае быть с новичками, которые задали "правильный" вопрос, но для решения проблемы необходимо что-то уточнить? Может в таком случае лучше оставить возможность писать комментарии от руки и добавить комбобокс с шаблонным текстом?

Comment: @RTK можно сделать голосование за хороший вопрос новичка, то есть набрал n голосов за - открывается комментарий, и тогда меньше вероятности, что напишут "иди на фриланс" и "скоро попросят дважды два запрограммировать", да и если напишут, новичек уже вдохновлен, что его вопрос отмечен как "хороший" и это компенсирует ругань

Comment: Если запретить минусы - получится уже не SO, а Тостер.

Answer (score 12):

Мне сложно говорить о ситуации на ресурсе в целом. Выскажусь по конкретным предложениям.

### Минусовать

Минусуют не участников, а вопросы и ответы. Минус на вопросе означает что «вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться, непонятен или не несет пользы». Рейтинг вопроса полезен как отвечающим, так и будущим посетителям сайта. И проставлять явно неуместным вопросам неотрицательный рейтинг только из-за «стажа» автора как-то странно.

Приоритетом для новичка является получить качественный ответ на свой вопрос. А ответ этот он получит скорее если вопрос будет четко сформулирован и содержать все необходимые детали. Полагаю что тот, кому здесь реально помогли, с большей вероятностью зайдет сюда снова чем тот, у кого вопрос остался висеть с рейтингом 0 и без комментариев.

Кроме того минусы являются важным сигналом для новичка задуматься о качестве вопросов. Иначе человек задаст первые 3/5/10 вопросов, нахватает за них плюсов, после этого «медовый месяц» закончится и его ожидает столкновение с жестокой реальностью наших джунглей.

Единственное реальное отрицательное последствие минусов для новичка это ограничения по задаванию вопросов. Пользуясь случаем хотил бы обратить ваше внимание на предложение по снятию постоянного бана на вопросы на англомете: [Question Ban: Should it be permanent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116450/question-ban-should-it-be-permanent).

**Немного не в тему:** вообще, я был бы не против повысить ограничения для неспамеров. По-моему на нашем сайте можно разрешать новичку задавать один вопрос в день независимо от рейтинга предыдущих. Так появится возможность обучения, на хороших вопросах человек наберет репутации, а плохие со временом будут собраны пылесосом. На английском Stack Overflow это привело бы к затору, у нас имхо не такие объемы.

### Комментировать

Вот я прошелся по постам участников с рейтингом 1 на главной и выбрал все комментарии подряд, кроме комментариев автора вопроса:

> что непонятно-то?
>   Что такое "не работает"?
>   Неотформатирован так, что компилятор запутался :)
>   Как минимум в стандартном С++ такие вещи, как `Mahsulot b[k];,` не работают. Ну и вот такая незавершенность - `cout << "mahsulot nomi :"` < - тоже здоровья не прибавляет...
>   Код приложите текстом, а не в виде картинки.
>   а так `c[0,::-1]` ?
>   `return ($hours || $days) ?` .. это что ли?
>   самое простое, сделайте переменную, которую например обнуляйте перед цклом, и по нулю выводите хидер и делайте ее единичкой
>   Может через pandas делать? Из большого датафрейма делаете меньшие с использованием специальных запросов
>   Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе.
>   юникодный символ - он двухбайтный, вы берете первый байт
>   скорее всего, ваш php научен подменять обычные строковые функции на многобайтные и должен работать `substr($string,1)`. Если не, `mb_substr()`
>   если бы я знал :(. Может, гуру подскажут
>   типо да, не можешь - на стороннем языке написана реализация

Не то чтобы все эти комментарии были очень хороши, но на этой малой выборке я не вижу того сплошного адского всевыжигающего потока сарказма, унижений и дедовщины о котором часто говорят. Есть полезные коментарии, которые указывают на проблемы с вопросом, есть комментарии-ответы, которые подсказывают направление решения. Я бы не стал грести все комментарии под одну гребенку из-за отдельных нарушений/несовершенств.

**Еще немного не в тему:** я бы предложил двигаться в несколько другом направлении —  вместо ограничения общения с новичком идти к его расширению, а именно дать новичкам доступ к мете и чату, чтобы у благожелательного новичка с реальной проблемой была возможность подробно обсудить вопрос и привести его к допустимому виду. Обращу внимание на пару предложений с метаметы: [Can we revisit the reputation minimum to post on a site's Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238568/can-we-revisit-the-reputation-minimum-to-post-on-a-sites-meta), [Invite low rep users to participate in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat)

Из того в чем я с Вами согласен отмечу то, что (1) плашка нового участника малополезна, (2) на сайте бывают недружелюбные комментарии. На таких комментариях можно и нужно ставить тревоги, для того они и придуманы.

P.S. Мне было бы очень интересно вместо очередного поста о том как неназываемые злые саркастичные «деды» ущемляют гипотетических заблуждающихся, но очень перспективных, а может, даже гениальных, «духов» увидеть пост с конкретными примерами «перегибов». Возможно, на примере будет проще понять что у нас не так и что можно (если можно) с этим сделать.

P.P.S. Если у Вас нет более ужасных примеров на уме, то в выборке выше есть комментарии вида (*простите, утрирую*) «Чё ты несёшь?». Можно попробовать разобраться что с ними не так, может что и выйдет.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT совсем со всем? :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в этом контексте `совсем` - наречие, которое пишется вместе с союзом  [Толковый словарь Даля](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/356414) или это шутка юмора? :)

Answer (score 4):

Если новичок, действительно сам хочет овладеть азами программирования, то он выживет, выплывет, - увидит, что минусуют не его лично, как автора, а его, плохо оформленный, плохо сформулированный вопрос.

Не раз слышал от других отвечающих и сам сталкивался, что очень часто приходится доставать клещи и тащить, тащить ими из вопрошающих, что же они хотят получить в итоге, в ответе. Весьма вероятно получить, после затраченных усилий, ответ, - `Мне это не подходит`
Все мы люди.. Может отвечающий и воздержится тут же от минуса, но попав в такую ситуацию не один раз, будет минусовать подобные вопросы.

### Извечный вопрос: кто виноват и что делать?

Не помогут никакие новые правила по ограничению минусования новичков .
Что мы можем сделать с готовым продуктом нашего образования, основанного на тестировании, угадайке.

Минусовать нужно авторов таких школьных программ, которые не учат самостоятельно мыслить, творчески изучать новое. Клипповое мышление начисто убило фантазию, воображение.

Поэтому на SO  обилие вопросов, - сделать как на этой картинке или как на этом сайте.

*Что реально можно сделать в этой ситуации?*

Поддерживать плюсами новичков, у которых проглядывается желание, а главное есть попытки, что-то понять и сделать самому.

Для плохо оформленных вопросов можно:

- Сделать паузу в постановке в очередь на закрытие.
- В комментарии к `нулевому` вопросу дать ссылку на пункт правил, - [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- или будет  более эффективно  заготовить ссылку на образец-эталон уже
  заданного вопроса.
- Если после этого не будет от вопрошающего попыток улучшить вопрос, то
  уж тогда ...

По крайней мере, так мы уменьшим  многочисленные обвинения в недружелюбности и несправедливости.

Answer (score 3):

### О поведении

> "Старые" участники тоже без злых намерений начинают минусовать и
>   иронизировать, мол, тут не фриланс, мол скоро начнут сложение двух
>   числе просить запрограммировать (тоже, без всякой ненависти)

Это непорядочно.
Точно могу сказать, что на нашем ресурсе не принято иронизировать и посылать на фриланс.

Лично я за "старожилами" такого поведения не замечаю. Даже наоборот, вижу, что люди с большой репутацией всячески стремятся поддерживать новичков.
Конечно, все мы не без греха (и я в том числе), иногда можно увидеть подобные комментарии от "старичков", но это исключения.

Систематической травлей занимаются, по моим наблюдениям, как раз сами новички (примерно до 1к репутации).

> Но бедный новичёк воспринимает все это как травлю, а вовсе не как
>   дружеское и доброжелательное (или равнодушное) подкалывание.

Я бы и сам это так воспринял. Травля слишком грубое слово, но такие комментарии я нахожу унизительными.

---

### О предложении

Считаю, что запрет на минусование вопросов новых участников и "закрытие" комментариев — это ***плохая идея***.

#### Минусы

Минусы довольно наглядны, они чётко отражают отношение сообщества к вопросу, к тому же это и есть одно из их основных предназначений.

Если мы отменим их, то новичку будет сложнее понять, хорош его вопрос, или нет. Отсутствие такой обратной связи приведёт к тому, что последующие вопросы никак не улучшатся, а возможно даже ухудшатся.

> Если не оттолкнуть такого участника, то он, скорее всего, исправится,
>   и сообщество может приобрести нового полезного участника (а может и
>   гения, просто протупившего в самом начале). Вот когда далее не
>   исправится, то тогда ладно уж, валайте...

Заминусованный вопрос не приносит абсолютным новичкам какого-то вреда: репутация не уменьшается (у новичка её просто нет), новые вопросы всё ещё можно задавать.
Если новичок поймёт свою ошибку, то обязательно сможет исправиться.

---

#### Комментарии

По моему мнению, новичков отталкивают лишь оскорбительные комментарии.

Но ограничив их, мы только усложним коммуникацию с новичком. Ведь тогда нельзя будет указать на некоторые специфические детали и придётся закрывать вопрос из-за недостатка информации.
Как вообще тогда новичок узнает, что он сделал не так?